# asp.net core (2.0) policy based authentication with rest services - HTTP response

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, http-headers, authorization

I have an asp.net core 2.0 program which has a MVC frontend using cookies/form based auth and some REST-ish web APIs which uses tokens. I have implemented a custom AuthenticationHandler for the web api that is token based etc. All in all the token based authentication works OK and access is granted or not based on the policy applied. The MVC authentication also works.

When the MVC Authentication fails, the user is redirected to the login page
When the Token Authentication fails, the result is a 401 Unauthorized

These are both fine.

The problem I have is that when I call the rest web API, and policy based authorization fails (eg, valid token does not grant access to resource), it falls back to the MVC 'form based authentication' scheme with an HTTP 200 code. I would prefer to have a simple 403 (not allowed) HTTP response. I have searched around but am not able to find a way to specify how the error is returned.

How can this be done?

Comment: I tried adding the following code to the end of PolicyHandler, but it did not have any effect: `if (context.Resource is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext)
            {
                authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;`

Comment: You could look at the cookie authentication [OnRedirectToAccessDenied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onredirecttoaccessdenied) event.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction. Indeed, adding an OnRedirectToAccessDenied handler using services.ConfigureApplicationCookie did the trick